# Toggled button using javascript and css class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying use toggle script on button through using css class.

**Problem:** When I click on the `button2` it get auto selected `button3` which is not correct.

Only at a time will active one button on click.

```js
function togbtn9() {
  $("#b1").toggleClass("blueback greyback");
  $("#b2").toggleClass("blueback greyback");
  $("#b3").toggleClass("blueback greyback");

}
```

```css
.greyback {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240) !important;
  color: #000000;
}

.f9 {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
}

.noround {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #CCCCCC;
}

.blueback {
  background-color: rgb(10, 102, 60) !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-12 f9">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="b1" onclick="togbtn9()" class="btn blueback f9 noround">Button1</button>
    <button type="button" id="b2" onclick="togbtn9()" class="btn f9 greyback noround">Button2</button>
    <button type="button" id="b3" onclick="togbtn9()" class="btn f9 greyback noround">Button3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click Button2 all buttons are getting toggled. This means button1 is toggled off, button2 is toggled on, and button3 is toggled on.

A simpler approach is to just remove the blueback class from all buttons and then apply it to the button that was pressed. See the below example.

In the example I also converted the `onclick` to a jQuery event handler so it's easier to maintain later if you add more buttons for example.

```js
$(".btn").on("click",togbtn9);

function togbtn9() {
  $(".blueback").removeClass("blueback");
  $(this).addClass("blueback");
}
```

```css
.greyback {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240) !important;
  color: #000000;
}

.f9 {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
}

.noround {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #CCCCCC;
}

.blueback {
  background-color: rgb(10, 102, 60) !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-12 f9">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="b1" class="btn blueback greyback f9 noround">Button1</button>
    <button type="button" id="b2" class="btn f9 greyback noround">Button2</button>
    <button type="button" id="b3" class="btn f9 greyback noround">Button3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, All is good only one query when leave the button1 the background is getting white instead of greyback. Can you tell me how to fix this.

Comment: yes, just need to add class `greyback` to `Button1`. I updated the example too.